# Swift: Which is the proper way to insert a changing text over time (ie captions) on a video with AVFoundation?

Tags: swift, avfoundation

I am looking for a fast rendering solution for generating captions from a file with text and timestamps. I am thinking about different solutions like: (1) adding multiple CATextLayers inside a CALayer over time, (2) creating an animation over time with a single CALayer, loading all the text at once, or (3) having n CALayers with a set of instructions. Also I am open to use open source libraries or pods.

What are your thoughts / best use cases on this?

My aim is to focus on speed. Many thanks

Comment: None of those is really interestingly different from one another. If your goal really is render captions onto a video, you're going to be using AVAssetExportSession. And that, whatever it may be, is not going to be "fast" (depending on the hardware of course).

Comment: Do you have any other recommendation (external library or implementation) for making this fast? Maybe some gpu / threaded approach? Many thanks @matt!